# Check two rows and insert new rows if they dont match after incrementing starttime

Tags: python, transformation, data-cleaning

I have time intervals data. If my duration is more than 10:00 then i need to check if the row and next row is having same description , if not then increment the  start timestamp by 1 minute till it reaches the end of the given time interval and repeat this for all disparate records.

I have tried for and if loop

```py
prev='0'
for row in df.primary_key:
    if(df['duration']>600 and df['starttime']!=df['endtime']and prev!=row[0]):
         starttime=starttime+1
```

I am not sure how to fix this.

I got an error starting that "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

input

[image]

output
[image]

Comment: That looks good so far. Where does `duration` come from? Do you calculate it in every step of the loop? Same for `prev` ?

Comment: It is a calculation ( difference between start and end time). I have it as a separate column , it is not calculated on the fly.

Comment: So probably at some point you need to get the `duration` inside the loop for each `row` otherwise you would always use the same value.